# Move duplicated key frames

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes, dopesheet

I have been searching heavily on trying to move the duplicated keyframes from say 25 objects and paste it to another set of 25(and doing so to copy to over 100 objects) I have been able to copy a single objects keyframes to multiple objects and duplicated multiple object keyframes but without being able to cut them and paste somewhere else. Is this even possible? Thanks
[image]

Comment: yes it is posible

Answer (score 0):

- select all you need to duplicate
- press `copy`
- and then place the marker of the timeline where you want to paste
- them and press `paste`

[image: example]